# struct address field takes the value of the contract address when initialized

Tags: solidity, remix

I don't know if this is a quirk in the remix IDE or something solidity does itself, but I've found something interesting and would like to know why it occurs.

I have a struct x in a contract Y which has two fields:

```
Struct X {
   address owner;
   address renter;
}
```

Now, when I initialize the struct by calling the function createX() in the remix IDE:

```
function createX() public {
   X storage x;
   x.owner = msg.sender;
}
```

The **renter** address field gets the value of the contract address Y

[image: example of address field]

Why does this happen? I expected the field to equal the zero address.

Comment: Your code does work as expected. I tested it and these are the results: https://gyazo.com/ae238ed170f44b00b9de61b221dd4935.

Answer (score 1):

The Solidity compiler should emit a warning for this.

`X storage x;` declares an *uninitialized* storage reference. That means `x` points to slot 0 in storage. When you store `msg.sender` in `x.owner`, it overwrites whatever was in slot 0 (the first state variable you declared). `x.renter`, since you haven't modified it, should still hold whatever your second declared state variable was.